# Dropwizard / JerseyClient ignored JsonProperty when sending http request

Tags: jackson, dropwizard, jersey-client

I have two REST services implemented with Dropwizard-0.8.
Both share an API dependency with following POJO:

```
public class Report{
  private String text;
  @JsonProperty("t")
  public String getText() 
  {
    return text;
  }

  public void setText(String tx)
  {
    text = tx;
   }
}
```

My Server has a rest recourse:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN + ";charset=UTF-8")
@Timed
public Response receive(Report dto) {
  //do some stuff with dto
}
```

My Client has a method :

```
sendReport(report);
```

with:

```
private void sendReport(Report report) {
    final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/.....";
    Response response = null;
    try {
        response = client.target(uri).request().post(Entity.entity(report, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), Response.class);

        final int status = response.getStatus();
        if (status != Status.ACCEPTED.getStatusCode()) {
            final StatusType statusInfo = response.getStatusInfo();
            throw new SomeException();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        if (response != null) {
            response.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The Client is made in the Dropwizard application class with:

```
    service.client = new JerseyClientBuilder(env).using(conf.getJerseyClient()).withProvider(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class).build(getName());
    env.jersey().register(service);
```

Where 'service' is my rest class calling the 'sendReport' method.

**Problem**

When I call the rest service of my server from a browser or with curl etc it works perfectly as expected with following messagebody:

{"t":"some text for the server"}

But when I run my application to call the rest service I get a 400 "unable to process JSON".
Debugging and the log messages showed me that the application sends the following JSON to my server:

{"text":"some text for the server"}

Which leads to the error that Jackson cant find a property "text".

Why is the JerseyClient ignoring the JsonProperty annotation?

Comment: Is it possible you have two different jackson versions (I.e. codehaus and fasterxml)?

Comment: Indeed! Another dependency is giving me jackson-core-asl from codehaus. I guess the classloader has problems with that. I will investigate this. Thanks.

Comment: The dto class looks very fishy with private getter/setter and having jsonproperty only on the getter but not the setter. Can't say it happens directly because of that but is probably related.

Comment: Check make sure the annotation and `JacksomJaxbJsonProvider` are of the same type (i.e. codehaus or fasterxml). codehaus annotation will not be recognized by fasterxml, and vice versa.

Comment: I investigated the double JsonProperty class. I could remove the one from codehaus. The problem stays the same. 
Sorry for the bad pseudo code. I corrected the modifier in the dto to public. The real code was public all along of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you using Entity.entity from jersey which has no idea about the @JsonProperty annotation(which is from jackson library) . What you need to do is do serialisation using a jackson library and give it to post call .

Comment: I am surprised that calling
Entity.entity(report, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
doesn't invoke the Jackson Provider internally but now I  have a workaround. Thanks.